# How to set TeamCity Command Line Runner default shell?

Tags: bash, init.d, teamcity

I'm starting my TeamCity agent on Ubuntu 15.10 via an `init.d` script like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          TeamCity Build Agent
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start build agent daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

USER="myuser"

case "$1" in
  start)
    su - $USER -c "/home/myuser/BuildAgent/bin/agent.sh start"
  ;;
  stop)
    su - $USER -c "/home/myuser/BuildAgent/bin/agent.sh stop"
  ;;
  *)
    echo "usage start/stop"
    exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The script starts the agent on reboot without problems.

However, my TeamCity build steps (Command Line Runners specifically) cannot find my executables, instead i get `node: command not found`. Curiously, if I start the agent from the command line as `myuser`, the exact same build step works fine.

I'm trying to avoid having to prefix my build script with `#!/bin/bash` every time. Is there a way to specify a default shell when using the Command Line runner?

[image: Command Line Runner Screenshot]

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the #! line? It's what every shell script starts with - it's like asking how to avoid putting your shoes on before you go out. Should you ever need to change your default shell to something different, you'll need to check ALL your scripts with that other shell before you can transition. If it's in a #! line, you can do them one by one. Nonetheless - it sounds like your PATH isn't set properly. What happens if you put just 'echo $PATH' in your script? And for that matter, if you put 'echo $SHELL' or 'ps | grep $$'?